# Можно ли заранее не задавать узкий тип адаптера SQL таблицы в C# и как?

Tags: c#, sql

Есть две одинаковые БД в SQL Server. Заранее я не знаю к какой из них буду обращаться, но т.к. они одинаковы по структуре, то пишу процедуру обработки. И вот перед её выполнение нужно как-то специализировать адаптер, к которому я обращаюсь. Например (сугубо по смыслу, этот код не работает):

```
TableAdapter Ptb;
DataTable person;
if (DB_ID == 0)
{
   Ptb = new Test1DataSetTableAdapters.MYTABLETableAdapter();
} else
{
   Ptb = new Test2DataSetTableAdapters.MYTABLETableAdapter();
}
person = Ptb.GetDataByUID(param);
```

Comment: Строку подключения меняйте

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет. У каждого датаСета свои строки. Каждый датаСет хранит инфу из нужной БД. Ковырять готовый объект - не будет хорошо.

Comment: Не нужно ковырять готовый обьект. Создавайте обьект фабричным методом в зависимости от входящих условий.